# First Description of how to Remove Radicals from Equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview, polynomials

Who first described the technique of removing radicals as indicated in the answers to questions [Tools for Removing Radicals from Equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176610/tools-for-removing-radicals-from-equations) and [Rewrite sum of radicals equation as polynomial equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177765/rewrite-sum-of-radicals-equation-as-polynomial-equation) ?

When has it been described the first time and,  what was the motivation? Was it actually an equation that involved square roots etc., or, has it been described as a proof, that equations involving radicals can be converted to polynomial equations?

I have already done a lot of online research without success; therefore I hope for answers from the MO community, even if the answers may be wellknown to experts in the field.

Comment: I don't really have an answer (hence the comment), but for some publications that are possibly worth looking at, see some of the older references I cite at the very end of this [16 November 2010 ap-calculus](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7288329) at Math Forum and see the references I give in my answer to the math StackExchange question [History of the theory of equations: John Colson](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493016/history-of-the-theory-of-equations-john-colson).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro thanks for the pointers to further information; that is more than I hoped for.